# Panda Data Frame Filtering Tkinter

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter, filter, scrollbar

So I'm building an APP to analyze stock excels i download using wep scrapping. I builded a treeview table with pandas data frame uploading the excel to the data frame.

So currently i have a data frame with pandas that contains around 12 columns and 50k rows. I want to filter this excel by ROA and ROE, both are titles of my columns in the data frame.

I already researched and a way to filter the data can be by searching something in the data frame. I already did that.

However I'm trying to do something more interactive with a combobox right now.

I want the combobox to have all the market sectors of the column
"SectorName" so when i select a sector in the combobox for example "India", in the treeview on the tkinter window i only see the data of "India".

I get the following error when doing:
`search_by = ttk.Combobox(main_window_acciones, values=tuple(df["SectorName"]))`

`TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'`

Image of the window I'm building:

[Example of execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqqci.png)

The code is looking like this:

```
def mainWindow():

    main_window_menu = tk.Tk()

    def ventanaAcciones():

        main_window_acciones = tk.Toplevel()

        btn_Back = tk.Button(main_window_acciones, text = "BACK",command=main_window_acciones.destroy)
        btn_Back.place(x=10, y=10)    

        def abrir_archivo():

            archivo = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='/', 
                                         title='Selecciona archivo', 
                                         filetype=(('All files', '*.*'),('xlsx files', '*,xlsx*')))
            indica['text'] = archivo


        def datos_excel():
            datos_obtenidos = indica['text']
            try:
                archivoexcel = r'{}'.format(datos_obtenidos)
                
                df= pd.read_excel(archivoexcel)

            except ValueError:
                messagebox.showerror('Información', 'Formato incorrecto')
                return None
    
            except FileNotFoundError:
                messagebox.showerror('Información', 'El archivo no se ha encontrado')
                return None

            tabla['column'] = list(df.columns)
            tabla['show'] = "headings"

            for columna in tabla['column']:
                tabla.heading(columna, text=columna)

            df_fila = df.to_numpy().tolist()

            for fila in df_fila:
                tabla.insert('', 'end', values = fila)

        tabla = ttk.Treeview(main_window_acciones, height=15)
        tabla.place(x=10, y=400, width=800, height=400)

        ladox = Scrollbar(main_window_acciones, orient= HORIZONTAL, command=tabla.xview)
        ladox.place(x=10, y=370, width=800, height=25) 

        ladoy = Scrollbar(main_window_acciones, orient= VERTICAL, command=tabla.yview)
        ladoy.place(x=820, y=400, width=25, height=400) 

        tabla.configure(xscrollcommand=ladox.set, yscrollcommand=ladoy.set)

        column_SectorName = df["SectorName"]

        search_by = ttk.Combobox(main_window_acciones, values=column_SectorName) #Error
        search_by.place(x=50, y = 100)

        botonabrir = Button(main_window_acciones, text='Abrir', command=abrir_archivo)
        botonabrir.place(x=10, y=340)

        botonmostrar = Button(main_window_acciones, text='Mostrar', command=datos_excel)
        botonmostrar.place(x=80, y=340) 

        indica = ttk.Label(main_window_acciones, text= 'Ubicacion Archivo')
        indica.place(x=200, y=340) 

        main_window_acciones.title('Wealth Management Data Acciones')
        main_window_acciones.geometry("1200x800+160+20")
        main_window_acciones.mainloop()
```

Any help on how to correct the error and have in the Combotoolbox a column of the panda dataframe?

Thanks a lot for the patience and help

Comment: Please provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Okey going to work on it!

Comment: I added new information as well as an image

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem.

```
            if name != 'Name':
            dfAcciones2 = dfAcciones[dfAcciones['Name'].str.contains(name)]
            name_entry.delete(0, "end")
            name_entry.insert(0, "Name")

            tabla['column'] = list(dfAcciones2.columns)
            tabla['show'] = "headings"
            for columna in tabla['column']:
                tabla.heading(columna, text=columna)
                df_fila = dfAcciones2.to_numpy().tolist()
            for fila in df_fila:
                tabla.insert('', 'end', values = fila)
```

Comment: So I basically search for a name similar to the one added in a text box in tkinter and if found, i update de table of the treeview